# Equi-mildly coercivness of the "Modica and Mortola Theorem"'s functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness

Throughout this section $\Omega$ will be a fixed open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lipschitz continuous boundary, and $W:\mathbb{R}\to [0 , +\infty )$ will be a fixed non-negative continuous function with exactly two zeros $\alpha, \beta$ ($0< \alpha < \beta$).

***Definition*** Let $(F_j)$ be a sequence of functions $F_j: X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ we say that it is equi-mildly coercive if there exists a non-empty sequentially compact set $K\subset X$ such that for all $j$
$$\inf_X F_j = \inf_K F_j .$$

The functionals are $F_\varepsilon:H^{1,2}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ (domain is a Sobolev space) with $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $u\in H^{1,2}$
$$F_\varepsilon(u) = \begin{cases} \int_\Omega \big[ \varepsilon|Du(x)|^2 + \varepsilon^{-1}W(u(x)) \big] dx & \mbox{if } u\in H^{1,2}(\Omega) \\ +\infty & \mbox{otherwise }\end{cases}$$

---

So what we are trying to prove is that given a sequence $(\varepsilon_n)$ of positive numbers such that $\varepsilon_n \to 0^+$ as $n\to +\infty$ there exists a compact $K\subset H^{1,2}(\Omega)$ such that for all $n$
$$\inf_{u\in H^{1,2}(\Omega)} F_{\varepsilon_n} = \inf_K F_{\varepsilon_n} .$$

---

I don't really know how to start and would appreciate some help, please.

I am not sure it is true, but I am very optimistic.

Comment: So $u$ is fixed in this? With what properties?

Comment: with $\inf_\Omega F_{\varepsilon_n} = \inf_K F_{\varepsilon_n}$ i mean $\inf_{u\in \Omega} F_{\varepsilon_n}(u) = \inf_{u\in K} F_{\varepsilon_n}(u) .$

Comment: So $u:\Omega\to\Omega$? You still need to specify a class of admissible $u$; is it $u\in H^{1,2}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$? Or just any function? Also, you probably want some assumptions on $W$?

Comment: You are right, I've been working on Modica's paper for all day today and I just assumed you guys already knew everything. Ops, I will edit now

Comment: About $u$, $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'm still confused: If $u$ is as you say, then what does $u\in \Omega$ mean?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I corrected it; and now, since I really would need the compact $K$ to be a subset of $H^{1,2}$, I don't think I can say it is sequentially compact.